# nestJS ManyToOne Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'joinColumns')

Tags: nestjs, typeorm

I am having an issue with OneToMany and ManyToOne.

The error I receive is:

```
[Nest] 818  - 10/05/2022, 11:41:22 AM   
[ExceptionsHandler] Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'joinColumns')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'joinColumns')
```

Here is the many side - variant:

```
@ManyToOne(() => EDC_PRODUCT, (prod) => prod.variants)
@JoinColumn({ name: 'edcProdId' })
edcProd: EDC_PRODUCT;
```

Here is the one side - product

```
@OneToMany(
  () => EDC_VARIANT,
  (variant) => {
    variant.edcProd;
  },
)
@JoinColumn({ referencedColumnName: 'edcProdId' })
variants: EDC_VARIANT[];
```

I have tried using JoinColumn decorator and omitting it. Both have the same error.

When I save product object the variants attribute is populated.

variants: EDC_VARIANT {
id: 121294,
type: 'S',
subArtNr: '1001-BLU-S',
ean: '8683702000855',
createdDate: 2022-10-04T20:21:40.622Z,
updatedDate: 2022-10-04T20:21:40.622Z,
version: 1
}

Any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Revised the definitions

Product

```
@OneToMany((_type) => EDC_VARIANT, (variant)   => variant.edcProd)
variants: EDC_VARIANT[];
```

Variant side

```
@ManyToOne(() => EDC_PRODUCT, (prod: EDC_PRODUCT) => prod.variants)
edcProd: EDC_PRODUCT;
```